# how to pass value from one WaterfallDialog to another WaterfallDialog in ComponentDialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

**bot framework v4**

I have two WaterfallDialogs in ComponentDialog.

I could store value like below in WaterfallDialogs

```
step.values[currenctCategory] = result;
```

but when i prompt another second WaterfallDialog from the first WaterfallDialog 
, i could not get the step.values[currenctCategory] in second WaterfallDialog

Comment: When you say prompt another second waterfall dialog, do you mean a child dialog of the one setting your CurrentCategory? Or a separate one all together?

Comment: I just add two waterfall dialogs  in one  ComponentDialog.
 And I store value in the first waterfall dialog ,then I want to get the value in the second dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the State to store the intermediate values that you will need in any of the parent or child dialogs. In version 4 you can do that using the BotAccessors something on below lines

```
 public static string CounterStateName { get; } = $"{nameof(BotAccessors)}.CounterState";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="IStatePropertyAccessor{T}"/> for CounterState.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The accessor stores the turn count for the conversation.
    /// </value>
    public IStatePropertyAccessor<CounterState> CounterState { get; set; }
```